# Model testing with mini-test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

*Fix & Original tests at the bottom*

I've got two model tests which are identical in format, but only one works.  I'm brand new to testing in mini-test or in general.  I've also read the issues list for the mini-test & just don't have enough skill or understanding to find a fix that works from the different issues posted.

**Goal:**  A working `.valid?` in my CampplayTest.rb file or an understanding of why it's failing & what I should be using in it's place (as devise's `blowmage` says .valid? should be used in place of .save!)

EDIT:  Apparently it's my model - not sure how that is invalid - see original error below

**Failing Test file here ...**

```
require 'test_helper'

class CampplayTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  # Test one missing from pair of ID
  test 'invalid - no campaign' do
    county = campplay.new(player_id: 1)
    refute county.valid?, 'Campplay passed without a name'
  end

end
```

**Passing test file here ...**

```
require "test_helper"

class County_Test < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @county = County.create(name: "Example Item")
  end
 test 'valid county' do
    assert @county.valid?, 'county must have name'
  end

  # Test duplicate
  test 'invalid - duplicate county' do
    county = County.new(name: "Example Item")
    refute county.valid?, 'county passed without a name'
  end

end
```

**I tried ...**

1. clearing the fixtures running just the test alone in `rails c test`
2. using 3 inherit paths for `test_helper.rb`
3. switching to integeration test helper in the test file itself
4. using setup function
5. pluralization by hand & by having the system spit out the pluralization for `Campplay`
6. Capitolizing
7. using .save! in `rails c` & `rails c test`
8. Changing the `rails generate test_unit:model article title:string body:text` example to match my model & fileds to `rails generate test_unit:model Campplay campaign_id:integer player_id:integer`
9. Changing the test file name & the class name in the test file to `Campplay_Test`

**My error message ...**

```
2.3.1 :006 >     c = Campplay.new(player_id: "1", campaign_id: "1")                                                                                                   
 => #<Campplay id: nil, campaign_id: 1, player_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.1 :007 > c.valid?
NoMethodError: undefined method `Campplay' for #<Campplay:0x00000004630890>
Did you mean?  campaign
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activemodel-5.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
(I truncated here to try & not spam people)
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
end
```

**My Campplay model ...**

```
class Campplay < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :player

  validates :campaign_id, presence: true
  validates :player_id, presence: true

end
```

**Gem list --local with "test"**

```
guard-minitest (2.4.6)
minitest (5.10.1, 5.8.3)
minitest-capybara (0.8.2)
minitest-color (0.0.2)
minitest-metadata (0.6.0)
minitest-rails (3.0.0)
minitest-rails-capybara (3.0.0)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.2)
test-unit (3.1.5)
```

**Full Guard file ...**

```
     bundle exec guard
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy.
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 2.3.1.
RubyDep: WARNING: (To disable warnings, see:http://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/wiki/Disabling-warnings )
12:46:03 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.4.6 is running, with Minitest::Unit 5.10.1!
12:46:04 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/ubuntu/workspace/basicB'
12:46:07 - INFO - Running: test/models/campplay_test.rb
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy.
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 2.3.1.
RubyDep: WARNING: (To disable warnings, see:http://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/wiki/Disabling-warnings )
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy.
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 2.3.1.
RubyDep: WARNING: (To disable warnings, see:http://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/wiki/Disabling-warnings )
Run options: --seed 24359

# Running:

E

Error:
CampplayTest#test_invalid_-_no_campaign:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `campplay' for #<CampplayTest:0x00000003e05710>
Did you mean?  campplays
    test/models/campplay_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:CampplayTest>'


bin/rails test test/models/campplay_test.rb:13

E

Finished in 0.275098s, 3.6351 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

[1] guard(main)>
```

**My schema for the Campplays ...**

```
  create_table "campplays", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "campaign_id"
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["campaign_id"], name: "index_campplays_on_campaign_id"
    t.index ["player_id"], name: "index_campplays_on_player_id"
  end
```

Rails version - situation probably should be fixed - but I am working a checklist right now & guard not accepting the version is just one more tweak...

```
mirv:~/workspace (master) $ cd basicB
mirv:~/workspace/basicB (master) $ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
mirv:~/workspace/basicB (master) $ rvm install 2.3.1
Already installed ruby-2.3.1.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.1
```

**FIX**

Was simple, it was corrupted files ...

1. rails destroy model Campplay
2. rails g migration dropCampplay
3. in the migration file did a `drop_table :campplays`
4. ran the `rails g model Campplay campaign:references player:references`
5. rails db:migrate
6. copy & pasted my previous model code I had save
7. copy & pasted original test code I had saved

**Copy of the final test file ...**

```
require 'test_helper'

class CampplayTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'valid Campplay' do
    cp = Campplay.new(player_id: "1", campaign_id: "1")
    assert cp.valid?, 'Campplay must have player_id'
  end

  # Test one missing from pair of ID
  test 'invalid - no campaign' do
    cp = Campplay.new(player_id: 1)
    refute cp.valid?, 'Campplay passed without a campaign_id'
  end

  test 'invalid - no player' do
    cp = Campplay.new(campaign_id: 1)
    refute cp.valid?, 'Campplay passed without a name'
  end

end
```

I credited the fix to @gaston as he spent time on it

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear what you're trying to do. Where is your test file? Are you aware that `rails c` opens a console and does not run tests?

Comment: Hi @sixty4bit ... I thought the mapping in console should show the issue more clearly than the test file.  I want the `.valid?` to work.  Also, the `rails c test` is something i pulled out of the rails documentation that loads the test env for you in rails console to use to pull error messages - which as far as it claims is the same as running your test file.  I will update more on the issue.

Comment: can you show campaign and Campplay classes?, what error  "test 'invalid - no campaign'" throws?

Comment: I updated model - the error message is right in the middle of the code spam ... `NoMethodError: undefined method 'Campplay' for #<Campplay:0x00000004630890>`

Comment: Do you have any other methods in Campplay?

Comment: I don't for the past day - originally 24 hours ago I had validates presence of in there before I installed guard.  Added schema too - since 1 of the 30+ Stackoverflows said something about db constraints can do weird things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should update ruby

> Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 2.3.1.

2) the error was a capital C:

```
class CampplayTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'invalid - no campaign' do
    county = Campplay.new(player_id: 1)       #you should change county to campplay
    refute county.valid?, 'Campplay passed without a name'
  end

end
```

3)However, there are some errors in the test. The test will pass, but for another reason, Campplay requires both id:

```
validates :campaign_id, presence: true
validates :player_id, presence: true
```

Valid will fail because of the id, not because of name. You should add:

```
validates :name, presence: true #optional  ,length: { minimum: 1 }
```

4)I'd recommend [shoulda-matches](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)

Doing so, the entire test will be replaced with

```
class CampplayTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  should validate_presence_of(:name)
  should validate_presence_of(:player_id)
  should validate_presence_of(:campaign_id)
  should belong_to(:campaign)
  should belong_to(:player)
end
```

Comment: Yea, I've done the campplay/Campplay thing so many times in there & added removed validations was the first step.  I copy & pasted in the working tests several times adapting them too - that's why I finally after the 8th time just started leaving county as the var name until I got a handle on the failure.  I did upgrade both rvm & installed ruby 2.3.1 - for some reason it's not taking with guard... I added the version output to bottom of page...

Comment: Sorry - should have explicitly said no - it didn't work.  At this point I'm going to destroy the model, drop the table & restart - it absolutely has to be a corrupt file somewhere since I'm the only one this particular thing happens too (if it's not inheritance from the test_helper.rb) ... but you would have mentioned that already.  On the shoulda matchers - I keep seeing that and rspec - but at this point, I'm juggling 3 major languages on 5 frameworks & rails alone must have me learning a gem every other day...it'd be more frequently but none of them quite work for me right out of the box...

Comment: Ok, I destroyed model & dropped the left over table - it was just something corrupted.  I had originally kept this code in a duplicate file which I pasted in ... will update original question to reflect the fix in a second (you noted the test will fail earlier - that is what I wanted, as in my original code you'll see i used refute which makes the structure match every other rails test out there).

Comment: Oh, one interesting thing ... at the end I ran the code before I dropped it - if I had - I would have clearly seen that the relationship wasn't working either.  I have been trying to do the testing automatically instead of manually, but this taught me that automatic testing by itself is a horrible idea.